# JVM unable to create a thread in Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, multithreading, cloud-foundry, java-threads

I'm using Spring boot for the application. There is a particular controller when called, makes a couple of independent requests using OkHttpClient. I am using a thread pool of 200 threads to make these calls. It works absolutely fine in the local environment. However, when deployed to cloud foundry, it shows up an error as follows.

I have reduced the number of threads to 100 but the problem still remains. These are the memory settings in my CF instance -

```
Instance Memory Limit  8192 MB
Memory Quota  3072 MB (available memory 1024 MB)
Disk Quota  1024 MB
```

This is the error -

```
 2019-05-08T19:13:35.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:35.686  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-65] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:35.76+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:35.769  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-62] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:35.81+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:35.813  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-54] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:35.95+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:35.959  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-73] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:35.96+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:35.967  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-60] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:35.96+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:35.967  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-79] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.03+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.034  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-77] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.05+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.054  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-75] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.06+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.066  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-18] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.11+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.119  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-12] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.12+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.121  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-32] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.12+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.123  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-71] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.12+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Resource exhaustion event: the JVM was unable to create a thread.
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.12+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ResourceExhausted! (1/0)
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.13+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.136  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-44] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | Instance Count | Total Bytes | Class Name                                                                                                       |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.583  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-92] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.583  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-59] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.583  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-38] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.584  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-25] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 100796         | 11914496    | [C                                                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.584  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-78] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.585  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-67] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.585  INFO 6 --- [ol-2-thread-100] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 99630          | 2391120     | Ljava/lang/String;                                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.585  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-80] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.586  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-10] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 6940           | 2320424     | [B                                                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 41544          | 1661760     | Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap$Entry;                                                                                  |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.58+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 50549          | 1617568     | Ljava/util/HashMap$Node;                                                                                         |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 13832          | 1535128     | Ljava/lang/Class;                                                                                                |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 42807          | 1369824     | Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$Node;                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 22775          | 1279152     | [Ljava/util/HashMap$Node;                                                                                        |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 21141          | 1183896     | Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;                                                                                        |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 10387          | 914056      | Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;                                                                                       |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 11925          | 913696      | [Ljava/lang/Object;                                                                                              |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2202           | 618392      | [I                                                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 36548          | 584768      | Ljava/lang/Object;                                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.59+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1168           | 485888      | Lcom/sap/LMChatbot/services/metricSearch;                                                                        |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 992            | 372992      | Ljava/lang/Thread;                                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 200            | 370440      | [Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$Node;                                                                   |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 18205          | 291280      | Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;                                                                                        |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1              | 262160      | [Lorg/h2/mvstore/MVMap;                                                                                          |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 8144           | 195456      | Ljava/util/ArrayList;                                                                                            |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2277           | 182544      | [Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry;                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 7532           | 172640      | [Ljava/lang/Class;                                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2964           | 142272      | Lorg/json/simple/JSONObject;                                                                                     |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.60+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2177           | 121576      | [Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;                                                                                |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2406           | 114776      | [Ljava/lang/String;                                                                                              |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 4127           | 99048       | Lorg/springframework/core/MethodClassKey;                                                                        |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1986           | 95328       | Ljava/util/HashMap;                                                                                              |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 845            | 94640       | Ljava/net/SocksSocketImpl;                                                                                       |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2319           | 92760       | Ljava/util/TreeMap$Entry;                                                                                        |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1648           | 92288       | Lokio/Okio$4;                                                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2185           | 87400       | Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;                                                                             |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 3042           | 73008       | Ljava/util/Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList;                                                             |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.61+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2242           | 71744       | Ljava/util/LinkedList;                                                                                           |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2612           | 62688       | Ljava/util/LinkedList$Node;                                                                                      |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 826            | 59472       | Lokhttp3/internal/connection/RealConnection;                                                                     |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1846           | 59072       | Ljava/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock$NonfairSync;                                                           |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 801            | 57672       | Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes;                                                       |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1778           | 56896       | Ljava/net/InetAddress$InetAddressHolder;                                                                         |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.625  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-88] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.625  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-48] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.626  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-64] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.626  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-91] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1417           | 56680       | Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;                                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.626  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-43] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.627  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-86] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.627  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-39] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 2277           | 54648       | Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap;                                                                           |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1671           | 53472       | Ljava/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue;                                                                                   |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.62+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 943            | 52808       | Ljava/lang/Package;                                                                                              |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.63+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1059           | 50832       | Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/AttributeInfo;                                                                   |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.63+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 884            | 49504       | Lokhttp3/Address;                                                                                                |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.63+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1505           | 48160       | Ljava/util/Hashtable$Entry;                                                                                      |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.63+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 998            | 47904       | Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;                                                                 |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.63+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 984            | 47232       | Lokhttp3/HttpUrl;                                                                                                |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.63+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1419           | 45408       | Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType$ConcurrentWeakInternSet$WeakEntry;                                                  |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.63+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1778           | 42672       | Ljava/net/Inet4Address;                                                                                          |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.63+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1776           | 42624       | Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress$InetSocketAddressHolder;                                                             |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1331           | 42592       | Ljava/util/concurrent/FutureTask;                                                                                |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 866            | 41568       | Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;                                                                        |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 10             | 41120       | [Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;                                                                                           |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 841            | 40368       | Ljava/net/SocketOutputStream;                                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 841            | 40368       | Ljava/net/SocketInputStream;                                                                                     |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 997            | 39880       | Ljava/lang/ref/Finalizer;                                                                                        |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1649           | 39576       | Lokio/Buffer;                                                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 819            | 39312       | Lch/qos/logback/classic/Logger;                                                                                  |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 960            | 38400       | Lorg/springframework/util/ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment;                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.65+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 960            | 36544       | [Lorg/springframework/util/ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Reference;                                                 |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.65+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 401            | 36336       | [Ljava/util/Hashtable$Entry;                                                                                     |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.65+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1135           | 36320       | Lsun/security/util/DerInputBuffer;                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.65+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1135           | 36320       | Lsun/security/util/DerValue;                                                                                     |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.65+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 560            | 35840       | Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap;                                                                         |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.65+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 743            | 35664       | Lorg/springframework/util/ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$SoftEntryReference;                                         |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.65+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 887            | 35480       | Ljava/math/BigInteger;                                                                                           |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.65+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 886            | 35440       | Lokhttp3/ConnectionPool;                                                                                         |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.65+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1413           | 33912       | Ljava/util/jar/Attributes$Name;                                                                                  |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.66+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 134            | 33712       | [[C                                                                                                              |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.66+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1351           | 32424       | Lorg/json/simple/JSONArray;                                                                                      |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.66+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 184            | 32384       | Lorg/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$ConfigurationClassBeanDefinition; |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.66+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1295           | 31080       | Ljava/util/ArrayDeque;                                                                                           |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.66+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 904            | 28928       | Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;                                                                                         |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.66+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1776           | 28416       | Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;                                                                                     |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.66+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 580            | 27840       | Ljava/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync;                                                  |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.66+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 312            | 27456       | Lorg/h2/table/Column;                                                                                            |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.66+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1135           | 27240       | Lsun/security/util/DerInputStream;                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.67+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 841            | 26912       | Ljava/net/Socket;                                                                                                |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.67+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1675           | 26800       | Ljava/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue$Lock;                                                                              |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.67+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1114           | 26736       | Lsun/security/x509/AVA;                                                                                          |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.67+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1114           | 26736       | [Lsun/security/x509/AVA;                                                                                         |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.67+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1114           | 26736       | Lsun/security/x509/RDN;                                                                                          |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.67+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1075           | 25800       | Ljava/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue$Node;                                                                  |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.67+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 447            | 25032       | Ljava/lang/invoke/MemberName;                                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.67+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 598            | 23920       | Lokhttp3/internal/http/RealInterceptorChain;                                                                     |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.67+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 297            | 23760       | Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;                                                                                  |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 140            | 23520       | Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;                                                   |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1443           | 23088       | Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet;                                                                           |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.682  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-83] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 960            | 23040       | Lorg/springframework/util/ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$ReferenceManager;                                           |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 477            | 22896       | Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/OperationInfo;                                                                   |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 290            | 22744       | [Z                                                                                                               |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 566            | 22640       | Ljava/lang/ref/SoftReference;                                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 1332           | 21312       | Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils$DefaultValueHolder;                                         |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.68+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 884            | 21216       | Lokhttp3/Route;                                                                                                  |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 882            | 21168       | Ljava/net/Proxy;                                                                                                 |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 326            | 20864       | Ljava/net/URL;                                                                                                   |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 630            | 20160       | Ljavax/management/MBeanAttributeInfo;                                                                            |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 824            | 19776       | Lokio/RealBufferedSource;                                                                                        |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 824            | 19776       | Lokio/Okio$2;                                                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 824            | 19776       | Lokio/Okio$1;                                                                                                    |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36.695  INFO 6 --- [ool-2-thread-56] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT | 824            | 19776       | Lokio/RealBufferedSink;                                                                                          |
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ERROR: PoolStats action failed: cannot determine memory usage statistics since the JVM is unable to create a thread
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR jvmkill killing current process
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-08 13:43:36
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b03 mixed mode):
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT "OkHttp ConnectionPool" #2406 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00005641e28d4000 nid=0x467 in Object.wait() [0x00007ff04cd4f000]
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:460)
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at okhttp3.ConnectionPool$1.run(ConnectionPool.java:65)
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     - locked <0x00000000e7f80178> (a okhttp3.ConnectionPool)
   2019-05-08T19:13:36.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149
```

I have also tried to reduce the number of threads to 75 but the problem remains. If I can work with 200 threads in my local system (16GB Ram Windows), then why would there be an issue with 75~100 threads in Cloud Foundry?

**EDIT**

Including the section of the code that creates the threads-

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        for (Object metricObj : metrics) {
            JSONObject metric = (JSONObject) metricObj;
            String metricTypeId = (String) metric.get("MetricTypeID");
            Callable<JSONArray> callable = new metricSearch(metric, type, systemType, odataHandler, systemContextId);
            Future<JSONArray> future = executor.submit(callable);
            // add Future to the list, we can get return value using Future
            list.add(future);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
```

So basically, for every object in metrics List (around 1000), I am submitting a job to the Executors, which has a thread limit of 100. So those 1000 jobs are supposed to be executed by a thread pool of 100 threads.

Comment: You didn't include it in the output above, but just how many threads are you creating in total? Not just the ones for your pool, but for other things too? If you look at the output you included, you'll see a full thread dump gets initiated (i.e. `Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM...`). Count the number of threads below that and see how many are being created. It sounds like more are being created than you might think. When you figure out the number it will help to see what limit you might be bumping into.

Comment: I am not creating any other threads in my code. Infact I tried to reduce the number of threads to 20. But the problem still exists. Also, updated the question to include details about the threads being generated.

Comment: @DanielMikusa In the edited code `metricSearch` , is basically a class which creates OkHttpClient clients for each metrics. I have around 1000 metrics. So, is it possible that each new client also internally creates a thread pool of its own, so finally 1000 metrics * 1000 client's thread pool which is causing the issue ? Could it be that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, each of these threads make a REST API call. I was creating a new instance of OkHttpClient for each thread. As it turns out, each client instance would spawn many threads of its own internally. So the total number of threads were more than what I specified.

After sharing the same instance for the OkHttpClient client with all the threads, the issue seems to be resolved.