# thread pool code deployed in CloudFoundry does not work

Tags: java, multithreading, war, cloud-foundry

My application has scheduler defined for an endpoint to process a task. This task has fixedThreadpool(200) code and deployed in cloud foundry. I commented out scheduler annotation and running this task using endpoint to see how threadpool works in cloud foundry. I don't see thread pool running, I can see when endpoint is hit, service is invoked and does not execute threads and leaves application.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(list.size();
for (final Data data : list) {
    try {
        executor.submit(()->{
            A a = invokeDetailsRequest(id);
            Long id = (a != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(id)
                    ? Long.parseLong(id
                    : 0;
            if (ids != null && !ids.isEmpty() && ids.contains(id)) {
                    .....
            }
            latch.countDown();
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
try {
    latch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
executor.shutdown();
```

I have gone through documentation and did not find much help. Could any one provide some direction on this.

Comment: Found this in stackoverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042466/jvm-unable-to-create-a-thread-in-cloud-foundry. but i am not sure what is OkHttpClient. I am doing the same thing he does. thread worker wraps a method internally calling a rest api. So suppose there are 25000 objects, thread's of 200 have to invoke rest api 25000 times.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible option is that exception is thrown inside `Runnable`.
And since you do not have try-catch block inside `Runnable` (and you most probably should have one with `latch.countDown()` being called from `finally` section) and you do not call `Future.get()` which throws exception if execution of the `Runnable` thrown exception, you will never know that there was an exception thrown.
And if at least one task thrown exception your latch will never reach final state.

Comment: I have commented thread and latch code and see application running with single thread model, no issues. I forgot writing latch.countDown() in finally block. I am sure it won’t have any impact with java code changes , it has to do something with cloud foundry yet I can try tomorrow java code changes and see how it goes.